# Who is this purple-skinned character?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

Who's this purple-skinned guy on the left?

I know [The Leader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinestro) is the guy on the right.

Could it be [Sinestro?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinestro)

[image]

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly like [Sinestro from Green Lantern](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Sinestro)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. It's clearly [Sinestro](http://www.actionfigureinsider.com/toy-archive/action-figure/mattels-dcuc-green-lanterns-light-5-pack-sinestro/).

Erm. That's it. Is that 30 characters?

[image: Sinestro]